# Не запускается vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, homestead

[image: Ошибка Vagrant]

На OS Ubuntu 18.04 установил virtualbox+vagrant. Сделал всё по [инструкции](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/homestead). Сгенерировал ssl ключ. Но на этапе "SSH auth method : private key" виснет. А потом вываливает вот это. Путь на изображении не верный. Сейчас он такой: ~/Homestead

Ключ генерировал командой

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Статус:

```
doox911@doox911:~/Homestead$ sudo vagrant status
Current machine states:

homestead-7               running (virtualbox)

The VM is running. To stop this VM, you can run `vagrant halt` to
shut it down forcefully, or you can run `vagrant suspend` to simply
suspend the virtual machine. In either case, to restart it again,
simply run `vagrant up`.
```

Проверил:

```
doox911@doox911:~/Homestead$ sudo vagrant provision
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: file...
Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.
```

Это баг?

Comment: В описании ошибки говорится: "make sure that networking is properly working". Как насчет сети?

Comment: @Eugen vagrant запустил. Но почему-то не пингуется и не доступен сайт homestead.test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы запустился Vagrant необходимо в папке ~/Homestaed выполнить команду:

```
vagrant init laravel/homestead
```